# AngularJS $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) Base Url issue

Tags: angularjs

My application base url is `http://localhost/abc/`, when I define the **angular routing**, the angular removes the `/abc` from the base url and redirect the page to `http://localhost/index.html`. The Url should be `http://localhost/abc/index.html`.

See the following code for angular routing:

```
var routeConfig = function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
            templateUrl: "index.html", // URL : http://localhost/abc/index.html
        }).
        when('/about',{
            templateUrl: "about.html", // URL : http://localhost/abc/about.html
        }).
        when('/contact',{
            templateUrl: "contact.html", // URL : http://localhost/abc/contact.html
        }).
      otherwise({
          redirectTo: "/"
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
```

Please help to overcome this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. You need to add `<base href="/abc" />` in your `<head>` tag. When you use html5Mode it will use this tag to set the base url.