# routeProvider - second when() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I learning AngularJS routing and can't seem to figure out why the 2nd when() on $routeProvider does not work.

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
<!-- In production use:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/li.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'}).
        when('/new', {templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: "/"})
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'persons', function ($scope, persons) {
    $scope.persons = persons
}]);


app.factory('persons', [function () {
    var persons = [
        {fname: "Dave", lname: "Thomas"},
        {fname: "John", lname: "Smith"},
        {fname: "Jason", lname: "Doe"},
        {fname: "Stupid", lname: "Guy"},
    ];
    return persons;
}]);
```

li.html ( for some reason, I cannot save this as list.html in WebStorm)

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width: auto" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <td><a href="/new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <tr >
        <td>{{person.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lname}}</td>
        <td><a href="/edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span ></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Whenever I click on plus icon, it throws me a 404 error. Even in the IDE, the 2nd when in app.js is of other color than the 1st one and the otherwise().

EDIT: Also help me with $locationProvider which throws this error when adding to app.config() - Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update from

```
href="/new"
```

to

```
href="#/new"
```

Comment: Is it a hack or is it how it is supposed to be written ? Cos I followed a tutorial in which the person did not use a # before. But used $locationProvider to set html5Mode(true) . But when I try that, it throws an error - Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!

Comment: It is not a hack. It is as per design. The one you are referring to is a another way of implementing thing. If you want I can add details for that too.

Comment: pls add them too nikhil. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: I found out an answer for you at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264754/angularjs-locationprovider-html5modetrue-base-url-issue Please check.

Comment: The error about a missing `<base>` tag is correct. All you have to do is add it to your `index.html`.....   `<base href="/">`

Comment: @JeffFairley I added the tag, but I don't see anything when I open index.html now.